# How to store images in google storage using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have worked with an example in `github`, where it uses `paperclip` to store images in the folder `system`. I knew that `heroku` is `read_only` file system, so i want to store in some other place and use it like storing and retrieving from `system folder`. I have read few options like using amazon s3. can i use google storage for this and if yes, how to use?

Also tell me if there are any examples for this in github, so i can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Paperclip`, [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3) is how you store it on Amazon's S3. But you can change storage to whatever you want by editing the `path` and `url` options in `has_attached_file`. See [here](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Carrierwave, in particular, [this](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#using-google-storage-for-developers) section.